# Как узнать, что передаётся в post запросе?

Tags: php, wordpress

Есть форма в Wordpress, данные с которой отправляются на почту. Проблема в том, что на почту ничего не доходит. Как мне узнать, корректно ли параметры записываются в переменные? `print_r` и `echo` ничего не выводят.
Вот пример кода:

```
<form action="#" class="send-mail" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="work_form" accept-charset="UTF-8" method="POST">     
<?php                    
if (!empty($_POST) || !empty ($_FILES)) {
$to = "тут мыло"; //естественно тут стоит настоящее мыло
$subject = 'Отклик на вакансию';
$headers = 'From: Вакансии' . "\r\n";
$result = vacansies_sendMail($to, $subject, $headers);

if ($result){
    echo "<p>Cообщение успешно отправленно. Пожалуйста, оставайтесь на связи </p>";
} else{
    echo "<p>Cообщение не отправленно. Пожалуйста, попрбуйте еще раз</p>";
}

}
?>
//далее идёт код всяких инпутов
<div  style="text-align:center; width:100%; float:left;">
<input type="button" onclick="AjaxFormRequest('success_messegeResult', 'error_messegeResult', 'work_form', '#')" class="redbutton"  value="Откликнуться на вакансию">                                
</div>
</form>
```

И да, будут ли письма приходить, если я тестирую на локалке?

**UPD:** выяснил, что проблема в функции `wp_mail`. Она возвращает fasle, поэтому письма не приходят. Буду смотреть дальше.

**UPD2:** Проблема была в том, что не был настроен почтовый сервер на локалке. Установил Sendmail, прописал в `/etc/php5/apache2/php.ini` строчку `sendmail_path = /usr/sbin/sendmail -t`, перезагрузил апач и всё заработало. Спасибо пользователю **s976** за наводку

> Вы тестируете на локалке? Если так, то все ясно. Почта не локалке не
>   работает до тех пор пока ее не настроят.

Comment: Используйте die();

Comment: Вопрос через что вы пытаетесь посылать письмо. Если через стандартный mail, то сервер должен быть правильно настроен. Посмотрите документацию на mail и на то, как настраивать сервер для нее.

Comment: `die();` ничего не выводит и не останавливает.

Comment: Так вы в die чтонибудь написали? Например die("OK"); или die("Error"); ??? И где вы смотрите сообщение, которое должно появиться? При использовании die, смотрите в консоле браузера.

Comment: Поставте die перед посылкой почты и проверте, отрабатывает ли.

Comment: Точно, я про консоль браузера забыл совсем, спасибо. Но вот в хроме в консольку ничего не сыпется, а в Мозиле с файрбагом `die("ERROR");` показывается вклодачка post, в которой вс мои данные, которые я ввёл в форму, как-будто игнорирует остановку.

Comment: Вопрос в каком месте программы вы поставили die. Попробуйте до функции отправки и после функции отправки. Может функция вылетает по какой-то причине.

Comment: Ставил в начале приведённого фрагмена, сразу после условия, ставил перед `$result`, перед `wp_mail`. В консоль не попадает то, что в `die();`

Comment: `Исходный код
-----------------------------57426245613039914521062146870
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="form_values[name]"
ertet
-----------------------------57426245613039914521062146870`
Вот такое я Мозиле получаю, как пример. Это я имя ввожу в форму и нажимаю отправить.

Comment: Значит падает еще раньше.

Comment: Т.е. у меня берёт post запросом инфу с полей, но отваливается где-то до обработки и отправки мыла?

Comment: Вы тестируете на локалке? Если так, то все ясно. Почта не локалке не работает до тех пор пока ее не настроят.

Comment: Не уверен, что даже до этого доходит. Попробуйте в самом начале документа поставить die("Hello World"); и посмотреть увидите ли вы этот вывод в консоли. Если да, то перемещаете это дальше по коду и находите место, где этого уже не видете. Там и проблема. Если бы сработал die до запуска функции отправки почты, тогда проблема была бы в этой функции (настройка mail на локалке), но если вы вообще не видете die выше функции, то наверное програма даже в if не заходит.

Comment: В if заходит. Двигал `die();` по условию из вопроса, потом по всей функции `vacansies_sendMail`, потом в `wp_mail`. Всё норм, до момента
`try {
    return $phpmailer->Send();
} catch ( phpmailerException $e ) {
    return false;
}`
В этом месте видимо срабатывает исключение или `$phpmailer->Send();` возвращает false.
Говорите, что на локалке почту надо настраивать? А вот это уже интересно.

Answer (score 1):

Пока я вижу три варианта, почему у Вас не посылается почта:

1. Не работает событие `onclick`. Предлагаю воспользоваться как-нибудь веб-инспектором, например, [в Chrome](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools) и проверить через `Console`, отрабатывает ли Ваш js-код;
2. Запрос не доходит до вашего `php` скрипта. Можно в самом начале добавить строчку `die('Hello, world')`;
3. В `POST` запросе нет необходимых параметров. Для проверки можно опять же воспользоваться веб-инспектором и посмотреть в `Network`, что отправляет по сети.

Comment: Я `die();` везде ставил, и в начале приведённого фрагмента кода и в конце и перед вызовом `wp-mail` и ничего не выводится в консоль.

Comment: @Cuthbert_Allgood, значит до исполнения `php` кода дело не доходит. Посмотри `javascript` ошибки в консоли браузера.